# Is the `<<` operator equivalent to `pow(2,n)` in python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, bitwise-operators

In the python documentation for python 3.5 https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html

It is said that a left shift bitwise operator `int << n` is equivalent to the expression `int * pow(2,n)` but without overflow checking.

But since python automatically promotes integers to longs of arbitrary precision, does this mean that there is literally no difference (since there cant technically ever be an overflow)?

Comment: Not sure about overflows, but they're different for `4 * pow(2, -1)` and `4 << -1`

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler "Negative shift counts are illegal and cause a ValueError to be raised."

Comment: @EliSadoff whereas pow(2, -1) is fine, therefore they're different. If the question is "does this mean that there is literally no difference", literally there is a difference

Comment: @EliSadoff So basically the difference lies with the negatives, and I dont have to worry about overflow? Can python even have overflows?

Comment: Python can overflow if you use c-based operations. For example, `numpy` has overflows, but python itself does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not have to worry about overflows in Python unless you are using operations that involve data types that can be overflowed. This does not include Python's built in number types (`int`, `float`, `long`, `complex`).

For positive values of `n`, the documentation holds. The reason they specify that overflow checking is done is because external libraries, especially those implemented in C, are subject to overflow if such checking is not being done.

As mentioned in the documentation for `pow`, this is also equivalent to `int * (2**n)`.